# How to use std::transform with container without push_back?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a container that has no `push_back()` method. But this container has an iterator on `begin()`and `end()`.

I would like to use `std::transform()` to output into that container. But `std::back_inserter` needs to call `push_back()` on the output container.

Is it possible to use `std::transform()` to output into a container that just supports direct assignment? Like:

```
for (auto item : containerNoPushBack)
{
    item = calculateValue();
}
```

Or indexed assignment like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < containerNoPushBack.size(); ++i)
{
    item[i] = calculateValue();
}
```

Comment: Can you use [std::inserter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)?

Comment: what kind of container is it? Is it some custom made or something like `std::map`?

Comment: It is a custom made container that allocates memory on creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a plain `std::transform` with `begin` and `end` iterators. No need for `std::back_inserter` or even an `std::inserter`.

For example, `std::array` does not support the `push_back` method, but `std::transform` works on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::array<int, 5> arr{};

    // note the lack of std::back_inserter just below
    std::transform(data.cbegin(), data.cend(), arr.begin(),
            [](auto i) {
                return i * i;
            });

    for (const auto i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' '; // prints 1, 4, 9, 16, 25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can do `item[i]` (i.e. your container has enough elements in it), then you can simply use `your_container.begin()` in `std::transform`, no need for `std::back_inserter`. `std::back_inserter` is just a nice way to avoid explicitly resizing containers before applying it.

The following snippets will both fill `my_output` with contents of `my_input`:

```
std::vector<int> my_output;
std::transform(my_input.begin(), my_input.end(), std::back_inserter(my_output), [](const auto& arg){return arg;});

std::vector<int> my_output;
my_output.resize(my_input.size());
std::transform(my_input.begin(), my_input.end(), my_output.begin(), [](const auto& arg){return arg;});
```

Comment: Mr. pedantic here: The snippets are not really equivalent, but have only similar effect - The second snippet will probably yield a vector with smaller capacity, and may be actually faster than the first one, depending on the size of the input and on the speed of default constructing the elements (I didn't downvote, BTW)

Comment: @CássioRenan Good remark, I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: To clarify, `item[i]` being doable is not a requirement of `std::transform` i.e. there is no need for a random access container. All that is needed is a mutable iterator. The requirement in the parentheses is the important one *(i.e. your container has enough elements in it)*.

Comment: Regarding the two snippets, you can use `reserve` in first to end up with the same capacity as the second, and may just as well be faster, since you just initialise the element once, rather than value initialise, and then assign that the latter does.

Answer (score 2):

`std::transform` does use "direct assignment". only if you need to push the elements you would use a `back_inserter`, if the target has already elements you dont need that.

Consider the possible implementation (taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)):

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryOperation>
> OutputIt transform(InputIt first1, InputIt last1, OutputIt d_first, 
>                    UnaryOperation unary_op)
> {
>     while (first1 != last1) {
>         *d_first++ = unary_op(*first1++);
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

`std::transform` itself does not push anything. Exactly for that reason you need a `back_inserter`. However, instead you can resize the target to have enough space for the transformed elements.